# Genetic algorithm chromosome generation

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I need to develop a system to select a team out of a database. Is it possible to use a Genetic algorithm to get the initial population (chromosomes) representing players as some identifier. Each identifier have its genes in a database which are used to apply various rules (such as requirements to be team leader, etc.).

Is GA helpful for such scenario?

Comment: Could you make your question clearer and more detailed, I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *can* be.

First, evolutionary algorithms work directly with the genotype of an individual. Stating that your are using identifiers to link an individual in the algorithm is either implementation details (useless for the question) and seems simply erroneous (you should load the genotype in memory for faster access).

Your problem is a simple combination problem. For a given number of players available n from which we want to form teams of size k, a total of `n! / (k! ⋅ (n - k)!)` combinations are possible. This is generally too much possibilities to handle on nowadays computing resources. Evolutionary algorithms allows (among others) the optimization of a given function too big for analytic resolution or where no analytic analysis exists.

You seem confused as to how to implement this kind of process. First, choosing a good data representation is important to get good results. You should first state every characteristics you want to optimize and what is their relation toward performance and if cross-relations affect global performance.

You should be careful, though: genetic algorithms can tend to get stuck in local maximums, be sure to keep your genetic diversity high by not punishing too hard relatively good solutions or with a steep selection phase.

That being said, the analysis I gave you was for a purely combinatorial view. From the point of view of a team, where context matters, evolutionary algorithms won't be efficient. For instance, if you need 3 attackers, 2 defenders and a goalkeeper, you should simply sort your player list three times, first according to the characteristics of a good attacker, then defender and finally goalkeeper and take the best elements (first elements after sorting) to compose your team. This will be way faster and give you an optimal result than using an evolutionary algorithm. Evolutionary algorithms such as genetic algorithsm would be of prime choice if you had no idea of the mechanics of the game played nor the inner workings of an optimal play.

Nevertheless, It is a good idea to begin toying with genetic algorithms to get a grasp of their possibilities and limitations. A good idea is to begin with a simple framework in a simple language such as [deap](http://deap.googlecode.com) or [pyevolve](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/) in Python to try your ideas out.

Comment: Thank you for the long illustration which gave me a clear idea, so as you say GA will not be the perfect fit for such a problem to solve. What about fuzzy logic or neural networking will it be effective than this. So far on the papers i read GA seemed to be the best fit with the facts they have given. A main reference that made me think that GA would be applicable was the below research paper http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/papers/k2011016.pdf

Comment: You should have talked about the Cricket in your question, it would have put us in the context. I don't know the rules of Cricket, but if you want to optimize a function which can't be simply solved by sorting and with much team-relation performance (whole [team] can be way better than the sum of its parts [individual players]), then genetic algorithms are a possibility. You seem to be stating as many buzzwords as you can; you should try to analyze their inner workings. You will then understand if it applies to your problem. Hint: Check the input and the output of your proposed techniques.

Comment: yes it was my bad that i did not mention cricket. what you mean i like to desk check and see how well it will fare. For example GA the initial population then what will consist the fitness function, crossover and mutation and then think of the final output right? like wise to my alternative technique like fuzzy logic also the same way right. Thanks for the help

Comment: Generic crossover and mutation functionalities are often provided with various frameworks and should be correct for your usage. You are right: you must indeed think carefully your data representation (what will your genotype represent - what are each gene role) and your fitness function to optimize. Good luck!

Comment: So you think i am in the right path to select my technique with a fine desk check and evaluation right. Hope i have not missed a better technique out side and stuck to GA and fuzzy. Thanks for the reply